# Do.call returning missing argument, for user-defined function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a function (call it A) within another function (call it B) (I defined both of these functions). To do this, I've defined some of A's arguments at the beginning of the B function, and then I've called A using do.call. However, function A is not recognising those arguments, even though they've just been defined. What's going on?

Context: I'm trying to run a simulation of a simple system. To do this, I'm breaking the problem into various sub-functions: one (genpar) generates random parameters for the simulation to use, and anther (indeffbasic) maps from parameter values onto variable values. I then combine these two functions in a new function called indeff. It's at this last step that the error occurs. I've searched around, but can't find any solution. Please forgive me if the answer is obvious. See code below:

```
#First we set up the data structure. 
#In this simple model we have N variables, and each variable has a value at each time period. 
#There are T time periods.
N <- 2
T <- 20
variables <- data.frame(matrix(0,T,N))
#I assign names to the variables, and check that I've given the right number of names
Names <- c("Movement", "AIpapers")
if(length(Names)==N){names(variables) <- Names} else {print("Error")}

#Now I assign the basic function that, given parameter values, runs a simulation over T time periods.
indeffbasic <- function(a0=5000, b0=100, a1, b1){
    for (i in 1:T) {
        variables[i, "Movement"] <- (if(i-1>0){a1* variables[i-1, "Movement"]}else{a0})
        variables[i, "AIpapers"] <- (if(i-1>0){variables[i-1, "AIpapers"]}else{b0}) + (if(i-3>0){b1*variables[i-3, "Movement"]}else {0})
    }
    return(variables)
}

#This function works:
indeffbasic(a1=10, b1=2)

#Since I want a1 and b1 to be randomly generated each time, 
#I define a function that randomly generates these values and returns them
genpar <- function () {
    a1 <- rnorm(1, 1.1, 0.02)
    b1 <- rnorm(1)
    parameters <- c(a1, b1)
    return(parameters)
}

#This function also seems to work
genpar()

#Now I define a function that randomly generates a1 and b1
#and then passes them to the indeffbasic function I defined above
#so each time I call this is like a run of the simulation.
indeff <- function(a0=5000, b0=100) {
    parameters <- as.list(c(a0, b0, genpar()))
    names(parameters) <- c("a0", "b0", "a1", "b1")
    return(do.call(indeffbasic(), parameters))
}

#But this doesn't work: it returns "Error: argument "a1" is missing, with no default"
indeff()
```

Comment: `genpar` is returning a a single vector (because of `c`). You can have it return a named list (by replacing `c(a1, b1)` with `list(''a1=a1, "b1"=b1)`) and then extract a1 and b1.

Comment: Thanks @lmo, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
return(do.call(indeffbasic(), parameters))
```

The first argument to `do.call` should be a *function* (or the name of a function), not the *function call*. So replace that with

```
return(do.call(indeffbasic, parameters))
```

or just

```
do.call(indeffbasic, parameters)
```

since the value of the last expression in a function is the returned value.